# jquery - how to iterate over specific json object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to display the results of a returned json object from NYT. It should display the first few paragraphs of each article. I've managed to call the API and Display the object name , and other two string elements , but I want to iterate over the object and return back the first paragraph of each article , how would I do this ?

```
var $nytapi = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new+york+times&page=2&sort=oldest&api-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$.getJSON($nytapi, function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    });
    console.log(data);
    $("<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join("")
    }).appendTo($body);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Did you look at the response json? the data you're getting contains 3 immediate keys: `response`, `status` and `copyright`. The first one is an object and the other two are strings. I doubt you want to add these directly to the page, it wouldn't make an interesting list. I'm guessing you want to display the array `data.response.docs`. Also, check the structure of each object in the array, you will have to change the callback function of `$.each`.

Comment: were you able to debug into the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON($nytapi, function(data)
                        {
                  var items = [];
                  $.each(data.response.docs, function(idx, obj) 
                                    {
                                                items.push( "<li class='article'><a href='" + obj.web_url + "'target='_blank'>" + obj.headline.main + "</a><p>"+obj.snippet+"</p></li>" );
                                    }
                        );
                  $( "<ul/>", 
                          {
                            "class": "my-new-list",
                            html: items.join("")
                          }
                   ).appendTo($nytElem);
               }
         ).error(function() {$nytHeaderElem.text("error");});
```